# Ember Binding changes from 1.6 to 1.11?

Tags: ember.js

I was using Ember 1.6 on an app I'm developing and decided it was time to update, but now I have a bunch of deprecation warnings, so I'm trying to solve them all. One of them is the fact that `contentBinding` is now supposed to be `content` but when I change it to `content` it's not binding... So what's the correct syntax to bind now?

PS: If you have different tips about removing all these deprecations please leave them in the comments.

Comment: Would you mind showing us the code you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
{{thing-or-something content=model.content}}
```

this would bind to a `content` property in your controller.

See this [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cukixa/4/edit?html,js,output)